# Drop Duplicates dataframe keep first or not empty value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to drop just for a name the double dates and take from the doubles just the first entry or the value if it is filled, e.g.:

```
01/02/19    Paolo   42
01/02/19    Paolo   9
```

The first one is kept: 01/02/19 Paolo   42.

```
01/02/19    Frank   
01/02/19    Frank   30
```

The second one is kept: 01/02/19    Frank   30.

When using **drop_duplicates** it removes almost everything and keeps just a small set.

My code looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

path = 'path'
filename = 'Dummy_File_Test.xlsx'
final_path = path + '/' + filename
print(final_path)
ws_name = 'Sheet1'

df = pd.read_excel(final_path, sheet_name=ws_name)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset =['Date'], keep = 'first', inplace = True, ignore_index=False) 
print(df)
```

The data looks like the following:

```
Date    Name    Revenue
01/01/19    Paolo   9
01/02/19    Paolo   42
01/02/19    Paolo   9
01/03/19    Paolo   10
01/04/19    Paolo   38
01/05/19    Paolo   
01/06/19    Paolo   
01/07/19    Paolo   41
01/08/19    Paolo   
01/09/19    Paolo   20
01/10/19    Paolo   
01/11/19    Paolo   3
01/12/19    Paolo   2
01/01/19    Frank   9
01/02/19    Frank   
01/02/19    Frank   30
01/03/19    Frank   10
01/04/19    Frank   
01/05/19    Frank   
01/06/19    Frank   
01/06/19    Frank   
01/07/19    Frank   
01/08/19    Frank   
01/08/19    Frank   
01/09/19    Frank   
01/10/19    Frank   
01/10/19    Frank   48
01/11/19    Frank   22
01/11/19    Frank   
01/12/19    Frank   47
01/01/19    Emilia  
01/02/19    Emilia  12
01/02/19    Emilia  15
01/03/19    Emilia  23
01/04/19    Emilia  25
01/05/19    Emilia  
01/05/19    Emilia  39
01/06/19    Emilia  30
01/06/19    Emilia  24
01/07/19    Emilia  4
01/08/19    Emilia  
01/08/19    Emilia  49
01/09/19    Emilia  24
01/10/19    Emilia  
01/11/19    Emilia  12
01/12/19    Emilia  33
```

The output should look like the following:

```
Date    Name    Revenue
01/01/19    Paolo   9
01/02/19    Paolo   42
01/03/19    Paolo   10
01/04/19    Paolo   38
01/05/19    Paolo   
01/06/19    Paolo   
01/07/19    Paolo   41
01/08/19    Paolo   
01/09/19    Paolo   20
01/10/19    Paolo   
01/11/19    Paolo   3
01/12/19    Paolo   2
01/01/19    Frank   9
01/02/19    Frank   30
01/03/19    Frank   10
01/04/19    Frank   
01/05/19    Frank   
01/06/19    Frank   
01/07/19    Frank   
01/08/19    Frank   
01/09/19    Frank   
01/10/19    Frank   48
01/11/19    Frank   22
01/12/19    Frank   47
01/01/19    Emilia  
01/02/19    Emilia  12
01/03/19    Emilia  23
01/04/19    Emilia  25
01/05/19    Emilia  39
01/06/19    Emilia  30
01/07/19    Emilia  4
01/08/19    Emilia  49
01/09/19    Emilia  24
01/10/19    Emilia  
01/11/19    Emilia  12
01/12/19    Emilia  33
```

Comment: The expected output looks just like the input dataframe. Or am I missing something?

Comment: no it doesnt, check the dates. the double dates are removed either if they are two entries for the same date the first one is kept or if there are two dates and one has an entry the other empty the one with the value is kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the change in column names `{Date:date, Name:name, Revenue:values}` because I generated own data

Coerce date to datetime and set it (date) as index

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index(df['Date'], inplace=True)
```

Sort name, date ascending and values descending so that the highest value is on top

```
df.sort_values(by=['date','name','value'],ascending=[True, True, False], inplace=True)
```

Groupby date and name while dropping all the rest other than the first

```
df.groupby([df.index.date, df.name])['value'].first()
```

If wanted to convert back to dataframe

```
df.groupby([df.index.date, df.name])['value'].first().to_frame()
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I receive somehow the following error: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'Date' for the groupby line

Comment: The code is:

`df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index(df['Date'], inplace=True)

df.sort_values(by=['Name','Revenue'],ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)

df.groupby([df.index.Date, df.Name])['Revenue'].first()`

Comment: I thought I stated I had changed column names. Date made it date, Name made it name and Revenue made it value

Comment: I understood, but it should also work with my column names or?

Comment: Ok, apologies for not using your column names. Wanted to try help as soon as I could and so generated own dataset. Apologies once more for any inconvenience. If the answer works, accept. If it doesn't, vote down for the benefit of the community

Comment: no no its fine. tried to use your column names but it works now but with the result I wanted. The double dates are still in

Comment: Cant groupby df.index.datetime and it works and still give multiple dates. Added my output for you to check.

Comment: Thanks. Two points: Paolo is missing until 01/09/2019. The second thing is that the code is still not working. Could you please post the full code from you and maybe change your header to mine? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code and it is working

`df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index(df['Date'], inplace=True)
df.sort_values(by=['date','Name','Revenue'],ascending=[True, True, False], inplace=True)
df.groupby([df.index.date, df.Name])['Revenue'].first()
df.groupby([df.index.date, df.Name])['Revenue'].first().to_frame()`

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it is working for intellectual honesty

Comment: That is the normal procedure :). Thanks again